# would this work in asynchronously in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

wrapping my head around async. would this work in a async environment?

posting and checking a param and returning true or false on post every time or will it block?

the users json is a standin for a mongodb request.

'use strict';

```
const serverport = process.env.PORT;

let users = [{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
    "street": "Kulas Light",
    "suite": "Apt. 556",
    "city": "Gwenborough",
    "zipcode": "92998-3874",
    "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
    }
},
"phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
"website": "hildegard.org",
"company": {
    "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
    "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
    "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
}
}]

let checkName = (obj) => {
    let va = users[0].email;
    return (va === obj) ? true : false;
}

let express = require("express"),
app = express();

app.post('/reg', (req, res, next) => {
    if (checkName(req.param.email) == true) {
    //render email already taken    
    } else {
    //render email is not taken and complete registration
    }
});

app.listen(serverport, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('server is listening on port: ' + serverport);
});
```

Comment: Sure this will work. What threw you off? The fact that function 'checkName' wasn't without the callback? If so, that doesn't matter, you can have your functions everywhere. Also if I may suggest good practice: use 'const' instead of 'let' for any variable that doesn't change (such as 'checkName' and 'express'). Also consider simplifying your return value to: `return va === obj`

Answer (score 0):

this seems perfectly okay, 
lets look at an example which might is not ok :

```
const serverport = process.env.PORT;

let users = mongoDb.getUsersAsync();

let checkName = (obj) => {
    let va = users[0].email; 
    // this point does not wait for the async request to finish, 
    // therefore will not work ! 
    return (va === obj) ? true : false;
}
```

ok this one will not work because the "users" variable is an awaitable or a promise depends on what library youre using.

how can we fix it ?

awaitable -

```
const serverport = process.env.PORT;

let users = await mongoDb.getUsersAsync();

let checkName = (obj) => {
    let va = users[0].email; 
    // this point does not wait for the async request to finish, 
    // therefore will not work ! 
    return (va === obj) ? true : false;
}
```

now the "users" variable waits until the mongodb async request finishes and grabs the data.

if its a promise we handle it differently -

```
const serverport = process.env.PORT;

let usersPromise = mongoDb.getUsersAsync((users) => { 
    let checkName = (obj) => {
        let va = users[0].email; 
        return (va === obj) ? true : false;
    }

    // ... the rest of youre code  
});
```

i hope that clears up how to handle an async situation in youre context, any way the code you presented above should work just fine since there is no async operations involved.